# Python ImageTK works then NameError

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I've got a GUI running and ImageTK is already being used 3 times, but every time I add a new line using it that line gives a NameError :

```
NameError: name 'ImageTK' is not defined
```

An example of it running correctly (in a function showing a dice roll) :

```
img = Image.open("{}.png".format(rand_num))
die_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
die.config(image=die_img)
die.update()
```

Versus

```
img = Image.open("pb.png")
grave_img = ImageTK.PhotoImage(img)
pb1.config(image=grave_img)
pb1.update()
```

So it exists, then it doesn't exist. Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typo. You mistakenly capitalized the K in Tk. `ImageTk` is not the same thing as `ImageTK`. `Tk` is correct, `TK` is incorrect.

Comment: I had copied and pasted that line before and just renamed the variable and it didn't work, but now it does for whatever reason. Thanks!